# Programming in C, integer distribution error, cannot find mistake

Tags: c, integer

I'm writing a code for a simple text based game, and when I purchase a car, the HP and TOPSPEED are registering for integers different than specified.
I've looked over the code myself, perhaps I'm not seeing it, but the Dodge Intrepid should register at 214hp and 140mph top speed, however when I enter the race menu, it registers for 320hp and 160mph top speed, which are the settings of the Mitsubishi 3000GT and the Dodge Stealth of the last beta. I imported the "race" code from the previous beta, being careful to omit any information about the cars used in the previous beta. If you can find my mistake or point anything out, it would be greatly appreciated (I'm including the code with my post). Thanks for your time. (I'm probably overlooking something) (Written in C, compiled and linked with DevC++)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
/*HP at RACE is malfunctioning, look over code.*/

int rnd(int range);
void seedrnd(void);

int main()
{
      char name[15];
      char ocar;
      char exit;
      char partsA;
      char partsB;
      char partsC;
      char choice;
      char dealer;
      char model;
      int bhp;
      int ohp;
      int tspd;
      int otspd;
      int score;
      int oscore;
      int cash;
      int bonus;
      int parts1;
      int parts2;
      int parts3;
      int car1;
      int car2;
      int car3;
      int car;
      int hp1;
      int hp2;
      int hp3;
      int tspd1;
      int tspd2;
      int tspd3;


      printf("What is your name?\n");
      scanf("%s",name);
      parts1=1;
      parts2=1;
      parts3=1;
      hp1=214;
      tspd1=140;
      hp2=490;
      tspd2=190;
      hp3=320;
      tspd3=160;
      car=0;
      car1=0;
      car2=0;
      car3=0;
      cash=40000;


      while(exit!='-')
      {
      printf("\nMenu:\n1.Garage\n2.Race\n3.Parts Shop\n4.Dealerships\n\n");
      choice=getch();

      if(choice=='1')
      {
           printf("Welcome to %s's garage:\n\n",name);
           if(car1>0)
           {
                 printf("1.Dodge Intrepid\n");
           }
           if(car2>0)
           {
                 printf("2.1988 Vector M12\n");
           }
           if(car3>0)
           {
                 printf("3.Mitsubishi 3000GT\n");
           }
           car=getch();
           if(car=='1')
           {
                   if(car1>0)
                   {
                             printf("You are now driving a Dodge Intrepid\n");
                             car=1;
                   }
                   if(car1<1)
                   {
                             printf("You do not yet own this vehicle\n");
                   }
           }
           if(car=='2')
           {
                   if(car2>0)
                   {
                             printf("You are now driving a 1988 Vector M12\n");
                             car=2;
                   }
                   if(car2<1)
                   {
                             printf("You do not yet own this vehicle\n");
                   }
           }
           if(car=='3')
           {
                   if(car3>0)
                   {
                             printf("You are now driving a Mitsubishi 3000GT\n");
                             car=3;
                   }
                   if(car<1)
                   {
                            printf("You do not yet own this vehicle\n");
                   }
           }
      }
      if(choice=='2')
      {
       if(car=1)
       {
           bhp=hp1;
           tspd=tspd1;
       }
       if(car=2)
       {
           bhp=hp2;
           tspd=tspd2;
       }
       if(car=3)
       {
           bhp=hp3;
           tspd=tspd3;
       }
      /*Begin Race Mechanism*/
      printf("Your selected car has %dhp and %dmph top speed\n\n",bhp,tspd);
      printf("Now choose your opponent:\n");
      printf("1.Rachel (150-250hp 110-130mph)\n");
      printf("2.Kyle (250-350hp 130-170mph)\n");
      printf("3.Darrian (350-450hp 170-210mph)\n");
      printf("4.Chelsea (450-550hp 210-220mph)\n");

      ocar=getch();
      seedrnd();
      if(ocar=='1')
      {
           ohp=rnd(100)+151;
           otspd=rnd(20)+111;
           bonus=500;
      }
      else if(ocar=='2')
      {
           ohp=rnd(100)+251;
           otspd=rnd(40)+131;
           bonus=1000;
      }
      else if(ocar=='3')
      {
           ohp=rnd(100)+351;
           otspd=rnd(40)+171;
           bonus=1500;
      }
      else if(ocar=='4')
      {
           ohp=rnd(100)+451;
           otspd=rnd(10)+211;
           bonus=2000;
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Haha, you're racing Eli\nNo contest here\n");
          ohp=2;
          otspd=25;
      }

      printf("Match-up:%s %dhp %dmph top speed\n",name,bhp,tspd);
      printf("              vs                \n");
      printf("Opponent: %dhp %dmph top speed\n",ohp,otspd);
      getch();

      score=bhp*tspd;
      oscore=ohp*otspd;

      printf("Let the race begin\n");
      sleep(1000);
      printf("3\n");
      sleep(1000);
      printf("2\n");
      sleep(1000);
      printf("1\n");
      sleep(1000);
      printf("!\n\n");
      sleep(2000);
      printf("The race is over, and the winner is!!!\n\n\n\n");
      sleep(3000);
      if(score>oscore)
      {
         printf("YOU!!!\n");
         cash=cash+(bonus);
      }
      else if(score<oscore)
      {
         printf("Your Opponent...\n");
      }
      else
      {
        printf("...neither of you, it was a tie!\n");
        cash=cash+(bonus/2);
      }
      printf("You now have$%d.\n\n",cash);




      }/* Closes choice 2*/
      if(choice=='3')
      {
      /* Parts Shop*/
      printf("Under Construction\n");
      }
      if(choice=='4')
      {
           printf("Press 'y' to exit\n"); 

           printf("Please Select a Dealership\n");
           printf("1.Dodge\n2.Vector\n3.Mitsubishi\n\n");
           while(dealer!='y')
           {
           dealer=getch();
           if(dealer=='1')
           {
              printf("DODGE:\n");
              if(car1<1)
              printf("1.Dodge Intrepid (214hp 140mph) $21,000\n\n");
              model=getch();
                   if(model=='1')
                   {
                        if(cash<21000)
                        {
                             printf("You cannot afford this vehicle\n\n");
                        }
                        if(cash>=21000)
                        {
                             if(car1>0)
                             {
                              printf("You have already purchased this vehicle\n\n");
                             }
                             if(car1<1)
                             {
                                 car1=car1+1;
                                 cash=cash-21000;
                                 printf("Thank You for purchasing this Dodge Intrepid\n\n");
                             }
                        }
                   }
         }
         if(dealer=='2')
         {
            printf("VECTOR:\n");
            if(car2<1)
            printf("1.1988 Vector M12 (490hp 190mph)$180,000\n\n");
            model=getch();
                 if(model=='1')
                 {
                      if(cash<180000)
                      {
                           printf("You cannot afford this vehicle\n\n");
                      }
                      if(cash>=180000)
                      {
                           if(car2>0)
                           {
                           printf("You have already purchased this vehicle\n\n");
                           }
                           if(car2<1)
                           {
                           car2=car2+1;
                           cash=cash-180000;
                           printf("Thank You for purchasing this 1988 Vector M12\n\n");
                           }
                      }
                 }
       }
       if(dealer=='3')
       {
            printf("MITSUBISHI:\n");
            if(car3<1)
            printf("1.Mitsubishi 3000GT (320hp 160mph) $60,000\n\n");
            model=getch();
                 if(model=='1')
                 {
                      if(cash<60000)
                      {
                           printf("You cannot afford this vehicle\n\n");
                      }
                      if(cash>=60000)
                      {
                           if(car3>0)
                           {
                           printf("You have already purchased this vehicle\n\n");
                           }
                           if(car3<1)
                           {
                           car3=car3+1;
                           cash=cash-60000;
                           printf("Thank You for purchasing this Mitsubishi 3000GT\n\n");
                           }
                      }
                 }
       }
       }
       }
       exit=getch();
  }
  return(0);
  }


int rnd(int range)
{
    int i;

    i=rand()%range;
    return(i);
}

void seedrnd(void)
{
     srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}
```

Comment: Reviewing your code in detail looking for bugs is a lot to ask of us. Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger? Or perhaps tried the old "when in doubt, print more out" technique?

Comment: You should brake your program into small functions.

Comment: Maybe you should follow the zero-one-many rule and use containers/arrays for data that comes in groups.

Comment: Best thing you could do is learn to use a debugger and debug this yourself. It will go a long way towards improving your development skills. Take this is your challenge.

Comment: I don't see the problem offhand, but if you used a couple `struct`s you might find yourself having a much easier time debugging this!

Comment: Turn up your compiler warning level. And **mind the warnings**!

Comment: Any time you start naming variables foo1, foo2, foo3 and so on, it's time to start thinking about some kind of sensible data structure. Any time you have foo1/bar1/baz1, it's time to start thinking about some kind of sensible data structure. One can handle 1,000 objects as easily as 3, but obviously not with code like this.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill-Sorry about that, I tried looking online for anything that can help me find an error in integer defining but couldn't find anything, I've looked over it myself, the debugger I have found no errors, I've never heard of the "when in doubt, print more out" technique, could you describe it to me? My brain is racked from the last several days of looking this over, the only thing left I could think of was to ask the coding community for help. Anything that can help me make this easier on whoever wants to help still, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   if(car=1)
   {
       bhp=hp1;
       tspd=tspd1;
   }
```

You probably mean `if( car == 1 ) {` ... this just sets `car` to 1, and "returns" `1` to the `if`. Then you do the same for `car == 2` and `car == 3`.

`=` is the Assignment operator, while `==` is the comparison operator! The first assigns a value to a variable, while the latter returns true if the are the same (note, for `char*` you need `strcmp()`).

Generally you should break your program into small functions and also check for the unhappy case (e.g. what happens if user inputs something not acceptable?)

Another thing that you should pay some attention to is this

```
scanf("%s",name);
```

what if someone types in more than 15 characters? You will start righting in memory you do not own and this invokes [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). One easy trick for that is to do

```
scanf("%14s", name);
```

This will restrict the input to 14 characters (and will keep the 15th for the nul terminator). Read more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

As others have noted in the comments, consider using structs to make your life easier. I haven't read the program in too detail to understand the exact structure of your game, but you could have for example a struct for the user:

```
struct player
{
    char name[15];
    car* owned_cars; //Linked List!
}
```

Where `car` is defined like that:

```
struct car
{
    int max_speed;
    int colour; //or even better an enum here
    int seats;
    //... etc.

    car* next_car; //Make the Linked List's next node here!
}
```

Also! If you make a LinkedList, one mistake that usually happens is that they forgot to initialize thieir pointers to `NULL`. So :

```
car* new_car = malloc( sizeof(car) );
new_car->next_car = NULL;
```

If you don't do that, `next_car` will contain a random/garbage number! So when you try to go through the List

```
while(new_car->next_car != NULL)
{
    //....
}
```

You will access memory you do not own.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I need alot more practice with C, unfortuantely I do not know what a linked list is or how to call it, or even if I can call it. The booked I learned from never mentioned linked lists...the scanf() placeholder helped alot, as far as the car=='1' etc. I'm not sure how this helps, I'm defining the value of integer 'car' and basing the values of 2 other integers based on the value of integer 'car'

Comment: @Carl, LinkedLists are data structures. You should get a good book, and use Google a lot. You can find a lot of information there. A good bood is this: http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628

Comment: @Carl, the main idea with structs is to group primitive data types (eg. int), and represent an entity. For example, back in school you used points in geometry, but in the back of your mind you knew a point is just a (x,y) coordinates. Similarly in C, we have `struct Point{ int x,y; }`! Besides that, it also makes the code easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: that link almost confirms my assumption that you are English, the assumption came from your spelling of "colour" (I know this isn't relevant but I'm easily distracted, you may very well be American for all I know...or heck, even from some place I've never heard of. Also, you've helped and for that I'm grateful.

Comment: I'll look into "struct" and try to learn how to use it, wow I'm apologizing alot more than i expected but, here we go again...I'm sorry, I'm very new to coding in C, or any language for that matter, the 1st beta of this game that I completed is so different than this re-vamp where I'm including a garage system, a separate parts shop, and a few more things that aren't in production yet. Would it interest you to see the smaller code for the beta, or to try the beta? it's supposedly less buggy. My code structure still needs alot of work.

Comment: @Carl, its alright. Everyone has been through the beginning phase. It should be better if you post any questions/problems you have in here, so you can get more opinions and more people to see your code. I am sure you will have many questions if you try to remake the same game, with structs.

Comment: (uh-oh, please avoid extended discussion in comments lol) I'll create a new project file and take a look at what I can do, I can almost guarantee I'll have more questions, if I don't call it quits 1st. it took me 3 months to understand that seedrand(); is called from rand();

Comment: @Carl, this profession has a big learning curve but it is fun. Even people with 20+ years of experience claim they still do not know much (especially in the `C++` tag). I would not be surprised if someone came over and declared my whole post as completely invalid :P. Have fun and good luck.

Comment: Thanks.I've looked into structs, so far they're confusing to me, as it turns out my book covers structs with one paragraph and only says that they hold data of different types and somehow they relate to pointers, which are covered the same way as structs, the internet is being helpful in figuring them out though.(cheers for google, because bing sucks)This is a hobby so far, but going into university with the exerience should help me in my field. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There's also an issue in the following code:

```
if(car=='3') 
           { 
                   if(car3>0) 
                   { 
                             printf("You are now driving a Mitsubishi 3000GT\n"); 
                             car=3; 
                   } 
                   if(car<1) // SHOULD BE car3<1
                   { 
                            printf("You do not yet own this vehicle\n"); 
                   } 
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

The integer distribution is wrong, because

```
int rnd(int range)
{
    int i;

    i=rand()%range;
    return(i);
}
```

is wrong. That ought to be

```
int rnd(int range)
{
    return rand() / ( RAND_MAX / range + 1 );
}
```

Read more here: [Eternally Confuzzled: using rand()](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx)

**Edit** to the comment:

With this, I specifically respond to your question `integer distribution error`: the random distribution will not be uniform. Meaning, some numbers will appear significantly less frequently than others, not the property of a true (pseudo) random sequence.

The [linked article](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) contains more elaborate explanation of precisely what happens.

<sub>You are using the `rnd()` function defined at the bottom of in quite some places, and to be honest I haven't gone through all the code to understand the implications on what the program does, so I don't know whether it *also* answers some of the *other questions* you (vaguely) desscribe in the OP.</sub>

Comment: the player HP and TSPD are not defined with the rand() function, so far I'm not having any trouble using rand() % range to define a random value for the CPU opponent. Please explain your correction.

Comment: It is the answer to your main question :) I'll edit my answer inline. Also, the explanation was in the link. It seemed fair that since you want to solve a problem, I can expect you to read an article, if you expect me to read all that code _(which actually doesn't run for me because apparently `getch` is not compatible with POSIX `getchar`. I'm guessing it is from the dreaded `conio.h`?)_

Comment: getch() is called from <stdio.h> as far as I can tell, it was recommended from my instruction book. That link is to an article which I've read before, I'm sorry to have appeared to not have read it. I re-read it when you posted it, thanks for the effort, I should more specifically define my questions, thought I was specific enough, I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

This section:

```
if(car=1)
       {
           bhp=hp1;
           tspd=tspd1;
       }
       if(car=2)
       {
           bhp=hp2;
           tspd=tspd2;
       }
       if(car=3)
       {
           bhp=hp3;
           tspd=tspd3;
       }
```

You are assigning car to 1, then 2, then 3: Use == instead of =.

Comment: doesn't using == check for a character value instead of an integer value?

Comment: @Carl, no! `=` is the assignment operator. Also, characters are really integer values. See: www.asciitable.com